# Windows phone emulator not showing security warnings from cross domain webservice requests

Tags: javascript, web-services, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am new to phone development so I am using the Phonegap (version 2.9.0) to develop a test application that connects to a web service that reads data from a data base and then returns the result to the app

The problem is if I run my code in my normal browser I get an security warning pop up but after that the code runs without any issues but on the windows phone emulator the application does nothing.

This is my ajax request to the webservice:

```
function CallLogin() {
                var CompanyID = "";
                console.log('CompanyID = ' + CompanyID);
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
                source: 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        crossDomain: true,
                        url: "ServiceLocation",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{ 'Username' : '" + document.getElementById('Username').value + "','Password' : '" + document.getElementById('Password').value + "'}",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d[1] == 'false') {

                            }
                            else {
                                CompanyID = data.d[0];
                                console.log('CompanyID = ' + CompanyID);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.status)
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

when I run this code on my machines browser I get a security pop up stating "This page is accessing information that is not under it's control, this posses a security risk, do you want to continue" and if yes is selected then there are no issues however on the phone emulator I get to the first console.log line and then nothing else happens.

I Suspect that this may be due to the cross domain request but if this is the case how can I get around that so I can make requests to my web service on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did I will post this here. Files are automatically added to a project in visual studios when you drop the files in the folder and hit the refresh button but this is not the case when using phonegap. when I was testing this code on my browser the project was loading the .jquery .js files but on the mobile application I needed to include these files manually